# How do I remove a duplicated Syntax highlight option?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have somehow added two SCSS syntax highlight options. One of keeps resetting to be the default (but it doesn't correctly highlight SCSS, it looks more like how the plain CSS highlighter does).

Every time I open a file I have to manually set it to be the correct one through the command pallet.

Here is a screen shot showing them both:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your installed packages. I guess it is from a third party package.

You also could deactivate them all and reactivate them one by one to find the package bringing the wrong highlighter.